# When is $(p - 2)! \equiv 1 (\bmod p)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I want to show when the following is true for $p$ a prime number. $(p - 2)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$. Could someone help me prove this? It worked for $p = 2$, $p = 3$, $p = 5$, so I believe it may work for all primes but I need to prove it. I don't know how to apply Wilson's or Fermat's theorem to this. I tried to rewrite it as $(p - 1 - 1)! \equiv 1 \pmod p$ but I still couldn't see how to apply Wilson's theorem to it. Could someone help me?

Comment: Use [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) $(p-1)!\equiv 1\;(\text{mod }p)$

Comment: @Pp.. Wilson's theorem says that $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$, which means that since $p-1 \equiv -1$, we must have $(p-2)!\equiv 1$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: Use [Wilson's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem) $(p-1)!\equiv-1\;(\text{mod }p)$

Comment: @Joffan Either one ... link.

Comment: i.e. $\,\ {-}1\equiv (p\!-\!1)x\equiv -x\iff 1\equiv x\ \ $

Answer (score 6):

From Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)!\equiv-1\pmod p$. Also, $p-1\equiv-1\pmod p$. Therefore

$$(p-1)!=(p-2)!(p-1)\equiv-(p-2)!\equiv-1\implies(p-2)!\equiv1\pmod p$$

for every prime $p$.

For non-primes, the question is actually rather more interesting. We can use a similar approach to the proof of Wilson's theorem. Suppose $n=ab$ with $2\le a<b\le n-2$. Then both $a$ and $b$ appear as factors in $(n-2)!$, so $(n-2)!\equiv 0$. If there is no such decomposition, then $n=q^2$ for some prime $q$. If $q=2$, then $n=4$ and hence $(n-2)!\equiv 2$. Otherwise, $q\ge3$ so $(q+1)(q-3)\ge0\to2q\le n-3$, and hence $q,2q$ appear as factors in $(n-2)!$. Thus we have:

$$(n-2)!\equiv\begin{cases}1,&n\mbox{ is prime}\\2,&n=4\\0,&n\ne4\mbox{ is composite}\\\end{cases}\pmod n.$$

Comment: But $p=3\implies(p-2)!=1\equiv1\pmod{p}$... And also, $p=5\implies(p-2)!=6\equiv1\pmod{p}$...And also, $p=7\implies(p-2)!=120\equiv1\pmod{p}$...

Comment: My typo confused you.

Comment: how did you get to $(p-2)! \equiv 1 (modp)$? I didn't understand that step

Comment: @MarioCarneiro. You proved that if $p$ is prime, then $(p-2)!\equiv1(\mod p)$. Why it means that $(p-2)!\equiv1(\mod p)$ only for prime numbers $p$?

Comment: Still a bit confused. If I have $$(p-1)! \equiv -1(modp)$$ I can say because $(p-1)!=(p-1)(p-2)!$, $(p-1)! \equiv -1(modp)$ can be rewritten as $$(p-1)(p-2)! \equiv -1(modp)$$. But I am lost at the next step

Comment: @marcus Since $(p-1)(p-2)!=p(p-2)!-(p-2)!$ and the first term is equivalent to $0$ since it is a multiple of $p$, you get $-(p-2)!\equiv-1$ and thus $(p-2)!\equiv1$.

Comment: What rule/theorem did you use to get to $-(p-2)! \equiv -1 (modp)$ that's the only thing confusing me, I apologize it's just hard to get my head around congruences sometimes

Comment: @marcus Recall that $a\equiv b\pmod n$ iff there is a $k$ such that $a=b+kn$. Since $(p-1)!\equiv-1$, $(p-1)!=-1+kp$ for some $k$. But then $$p(p-2)!-(p-2)!=-1+kp\implies-(p-2)!=-1+kp-p(p-2)!=-1+(k-(p-2)!)p,$$ and $k-(p-2)!$ is an integer, hence $-(p-2)!\equiv-1$.

Comment: @Mathematician171 That's because the question was only asking about primes. However, the converse is also true, which was interesting enough to put in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Mario. When you explained it with the steps, everything came together.